# Shift Divs Left Right if Screen Width Less Than X but Bind The Whole Thing to Each Block Individually

Tags: jquery, function, this

I have this code

```
<div class="row rowOne">
<div class="col-md-6 col-shift-right-js">...</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-shift-left-js">...</div>
</div>

<div class="row rowTwo">
<div class="col-md-6 col-shift-right-js">...</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-shift-left-js">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to move right div to left and left div to right if screen width is less than 991px.

I have achieved this by creating a function and triggering that function in document ready and on resize events.

```
function shiftColsLeftRight() {
    if( jQuery(window).width() <= 991 ) {
        jQuery('.col-shift-left-js').insertBefore('.col-shift-right-js');
    } else {
        jQuery('.col-shift-right-js').insertBefore('.col-shift-left-js');
    }
}

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
    // shift columns trigger
    shiftColsLeftRight();
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
shiftColsLeftRight();
});
```

This is working fine. 
But for only one block. 
I have multiple rows that needs columns to shift their position on small screens.
I can target each block by copying the same code and targetting each row by its unique id but that will increase code.
I want the code execute in only one row and then proceed and then affect columns in second row.
How can I do that?
I have tried

```
var theRow = $('.row');
```

But how will I get this in $(this)

this.find('.col-shift-left-js') and .insertBefore('.col-shift-right-js') but only for this row and then proceed for the next row.

I have also tried .find() and .closest() in the code but i am unable to implement it properly.

I want the same one function to work for all the row blocks. I do not want to target each row by repeating code and targeting each row.

Current function will also cut col-shift-right-js div from second row and insert in rowOne.

I have also tried this

```
function shiftColsLeftRight() {
    if( jQuery(window).width() <= 991 ) {
         jQuery('.row').find('.col-shift-left-js').insertBefore( jQuery(this).closest('.col-shift-right-js') );
    } else {
        jQuery('.row').find('.col-shift-right-js').insertBefore( jQuery(this).closest('.col-shift-left-js') );
    }
}
```

But its not working.

I have solved it by using each function.

```
function shiftColsLeftRight() {
    if( jQuery(window).width() <= 991 ) {
        //jQuery('.col-shift-left-js').insertBefore('.col-shift-right-js');
        jQuery('.col-shift-left-js').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).parent('.row').find('.col-shift-right-js').insertAfter(this);
        });  

    } else {
        // jQuery('.col-shift-right-js').insertBefore('.col-shift-left-js');
        jQuery('.col-shift-right-js').each(function() {
            jQuery(this).parent('.row').find('.col-shift-left-js').insertAfter(this);
        });  
    }
}
```

More solutions or simpler one is welcome.